# Loading a GPX file using OpenLayers 2

Tags: openlayers-2, gpx

I am trying to read a gpx file and add it as a layer to Open Layers. Here is my code snippet

```
 osMap = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        maxExtent: extent,
        resolutions: mapResolutions,
        units: "m",
        projection: "EPSG:27700",
        restrictedExtent: restrictedExtent                         
    });

    osMap.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ(
        "Leisure",
        ['https://api2.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/mapping_api/v1/service/wmts?service=WMTS&request=GetTile&version=1.0.0&layer=Leisure%2027700&style=true&format=image%2Fpng&tileMatrixSet=EPSG%3A27700&tileMatrix=EPSG%3A27700%3A${z}&tileRow=${y}&tileCol=${x}' + key
        ]
    ));

    vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("MarkersTrail"); 
    osMap.addLayer(vectorLayer);     

    osMap.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(400000, 400000), 0);

    var layer;
    var path = "filename";

    if((layer = osMap.getLayer(path)) == null) 
    {
        var gpxLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("gpx", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url:path + ".gpx",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GPX({
internalProjection: "EPSG:27700"
                    extractStyles: true,
                    extractAttributes: true,
                    maxDepth: 2
                })
            })
        });

        gpxLayer.id = path;
        gpxLayer.setVisibility(false, false);
        osMap.addLayer(gpxLayer);


    }
    layer = osMap.getLayer(path);
    if(obj.checked == true) 
    {
        layer.setVisibility(true, false);
    }
    else 
    {
        layer.setVisibility(false, false);
    }
```

However it is not displaying the layer? Think I've missed a trick here....

Answer (score 0):

Are there any CORS errors shown on the console log?  OpenLayers 2 HTTP protocol frequently fails to load resources because it uses unnecessarily complex XHR requests which cause CORS preflight requests which most servers do not expect or handle.  Preceding your code with a redefinition of the OpenLayers code responsible for the problem often helps.

```
OpenLayers.Request.issue = function(config) {        
    // apply default config - proxy host may have changed
    var defaultConfig = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
        this.DEFAULT_CONFIG,
        {proxy: OpenLayers.ProxyHost}
    );
    config = config || {};
    config.headers = config.headers || {};
    config = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(config, defaultConfig);
    config.headers = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(config.headers, defaultConfig.headers);
    // Unwanted code removed. DO NOT add the "X-Requested-With" header.

    // create request, open, and set headers
    var request = new OpenLayers.Request.XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = OpenLayers.Util.urlAppend(config.url, 
        OpenLayers.Util.getParameterString(config.params || {}));
    url = OpenLayers.Request.makeSameOrigin(url, config.proxy);
    request.open(
        config.method, url, config.async, config.user, config.password
    );
    for(var header in config.headers) {
        request.setRequestHeader(header, config.headers[header]);
    }

    var events = this.events;

    // we want to execute runCallbacks with "this" as the
    // execution scope
    var self = this;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState == OpenLayers.Request.XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var proceed = events.triggerEvent(
                "complete",
                {request: request, config: config, requestUrl: url}
            );
            if(proceed !== false) {
                self.runCallbacks(
                    {request: request, config: config, requestUrl: url}
                );
            }
        }
    };

    // send request (optionally with data) and return
    // call in a timeout for asynchronous requests so the return is
    // available before readyState == 4 for cached docs
    if(config.async === false) {
        request.send(config.data);
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            if (request.readyState !== 0) { // W3C: 0-UNSENT
                request.send(config.data);
            }
        }, 0);
    }
    return request;
};
```

For reprojection to EPSG:27700 you will need to specify internal projection:

```
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GPX({
                internalProjection: "EPSG:27700",
                ...
```

It seems the workaround to use proj4 version 2 isn't compatible here and only proj4 version 1.1 will work.

Comment: Nothing in console apart from:
OpenLayers.js:553 XHR finished loading: GET "http://test.domain.com/filename.gpx"

Comment: It might be data related.  Here http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/ol2gpx.html is working (although it needs the no preflight patch) demo based on https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Openlayers_Track_example but using data from a more recent example.  You could try testing your code with the same data url.

Comment: I have noticed my gpx file appears to be being loaded but is rendered in a single location i.e. each way point on top of the previous and not in correct location. Basically the bottom left corner of my map. Essentially 0,0. Could it be projection?

Comment: Yes, I just tried adding a GPX to some old OL2 code and had the same problem.  I've added the fix to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Mike, version 1.1 does not appear to be available on proj4js

Comment: I used https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/1.1.0/proj4js-combined.min.js

Comment: Thanks Mike, I think I am so close yet so far on this.

  window.Proj4js = {
        Proj: function(code) {
          return proj4(Proj4js.defs[code]);
        },
        defs: proj4.defs,
        transform: proj4
      };

    proj4.defs("EPSG:27700", "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs");

I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: proj4 is not defined" ?

Comment: You can replace all of that with the declaration in version 1.1 format `Proj4js.defs["EPSG:27700"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs";`

Comment: Here's my test http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/ol2-27000-gpx.html